# Div positioning not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have 4 `div` elements, one after the other. The 1st, 2nd, and 4th are working fine, but the 3rd `div` is not positioning properly. I am setting its position, but it's not following ...my code ..

`.mid_table` `div` is left aligned, but I want it to follow the coordinates given in CSS.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FKk29/)

### CSS

```css
#top_table {
    background-image: url(images/Round%20corner);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    height: 25px;
}
#bottom_table {
    background-image: url(images/Round%20corner);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    height: 25px;
}
#mid_table {
    background-color: #09F;
    left: 54px;
    width: 449px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
```

### HTML

```html
<body>
<div id="logo" >
 <center>
  <h1><b> Portal</b></h1>
 </center>
</div>
<div id="top_table">
 <!-- empty -->
</div>
<div id="mid_table">
 Content for  id "mid_table" Goes Here
</div>
<div id="bottom_table">
 Content for  id "bottom_table" Goes Here
</div>
<div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, do you want the `#mid_table` 54px from the left? It's working in your jsfiddle example and that's what your CSS says...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
position: relative
```

?
The position: absolute will only work if it's "absolute" to something else. So a parental ancestor will need to be positioned, eg position: relative

Comment: Where is this div meant to be? It look to me like it is following your code (FireFox).

Comment: Actually i wanted a round shaped table in which i will create a login form ...So for this i created 3 divs ,1st div contains the upper rounder corner part of image and 3rd div contains the lower one ..Now 2nd div is the one which will contain the form . So in order to align with the coordinates of image i am positioning the div 2nd and its not working ...please if someone can help me out ..

Answer (score 0):

With position: relative should work. 
(You already have the position relative in your css so I guess it was the guy who edited)

Which browser are you testing on? If it's not working for you, it might be a browser issue.

You can check it here.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgiust/Kabba/)

Also in your html there is an unclosed div tag at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see an error that could disrupt the display of third div.Only unclosed div before /body tag.  What is your browser?
Coordinates work with a given property relative position.